# How to write Buffered Image on HDFS

Tags: hadoop

In Map task i am trying to use  ImageIO.write(bufferedimage, "png", new File(outputFilenamepath));
i am getting exception as no such file or directory -FileNotFoundException.
Could you please tell me as how to write image file on HDFS assuming buffered image is present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapper task run concurrently on multiple nodes in the Hadoop cluster. Your method of writing with normal Java Writer classes will not work just because you need to use HDFS API to write the data.

Use FileSystem API -

```
     Configuration conf = new Configuration();
     FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
     Path inputfile = new Path("in/map");
     FSDataOutputStream out = fs.create(inputfile);
     if(value.toString()!= null){
        out.writeBytes(value.toString());
     }
        out.close();
```

Comment: Can we use javax.imageio.ImageIO class with FileSystem. i have to write image files on hdfs.?